# FPC and "upstream sent too big header while reading response header from upstream" error on nginx?

Tags: magento2, full-page-cache, nginx

As soon as I enable FPC in Magento 2.4.2, I am getting a **upstream sent too big header while reading response header from upstream** error when I try searching. It does not happen for all search terms, but for most.

My shop is running on nginx so I tried adding this to the nginx.conf:

```
fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
proxy_buffer_size   128k;
proxy_buffers   4 256k;
proxy_busy_buffers_size   256k;
```

Did not help a bit. Any ideas how to solve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I find this is normally down to the CSP headers. If you don’t need the module disable it using

> bin/magento module:disable Magento_Csp

And you should be back in business.

Comment: Thanks, did not help in my case :(

Comment: it works, thanks!